# Android BLE Device continually disconnects and re-connects every 30 seconds

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am following [Android's BLE apis](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) trying to connect to a device a read data from it. Scanning for, connecting to, and making a reading is fine but the problem is that after exactly 30 seconds, the connection drops -- only to reconnect momentarily(< 10 sec). Here is my code for connecting to the device's GATT server:

```
 protected BluetoothGatt initGattServer(BluetoothDevice device, final ConnectionCallback callback, final DataCallback dataCallback) {
    Log.d("INIT GATT SERVER", device.getName());
    this.gatt = device.connectGatt(context, true, new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState){
            Log.d("GATT CONNECTION", "CHANGED -- status: " + status + " newState: " + newState);
            if(callback != null){
                callback.onConnectionStateChanged(newState);
            }
            gattConnectionState = newState;
            if(status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS){
                if(newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED){
                    gatt.discoverServices();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status){
            gattServices.clear();
            gattServices.addAll(gatt.getServices());
            callback.onServicesDiscovered(gatt);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status){
            handleCharacteristicChanged(characteristic, status, dataCallback);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status){
            handleCharacteristicChanged(characteristic, status, dataCallback);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic){
            handleCharacteristicChanged(characteristic, BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS, dataCallback);
        }
    });

    refreshDeviceCache(gatt);

    return this.gatt;
}
```

The issue is that I am receiving unexpected callbacks to onConnectionStateChange with BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED, followed by BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED. This disconnect-reconnect phase repeats itself for the duration of the service it runs in and so the connection is not solid. The vendor of the device I am trying to connect to has an app that is maintaining it's connection but mine is not. What could be the reason?

Comment: What device are you trying to connect to? Maybe the device expects some kind of write, otherwise it disconnects?

Comment: An engine diagnostic reader -- meant to monitor vehicle odometer, engine state and such. [link](http://wlius.com/bluelink)

Comment: It is fairly common for BLE peripheral to implement an Idle timeout, since they are designed to last a long time with often only a small capacity battery. Performing any characteristic read or write might be enough to keep the link alive. How often are you performing a read?

Comment: Once upon connection and every 60s after that

Comment: I am not aware that android has any idle timeouts. I am inclined to agree with Emil's comment. If you enable Bluetooth HCI snoop logging in Developer settings then you can see what the manufacturers app writes to the peripheral, if anything, and copy it!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Mark Ch is correct in suggesting that there may be an idle timeout. In this device's case it was 30 seconds so performing a read every 29 seconds or less prevented the disconnects. Just wish they would have mentioned this in the docs!